# How to prove $|a_{2n}-a_{n}|<\frac{10}{27}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let sequence $$a_{1}=1,a_{n+1}=\dfrac{2}{2a_{n}+1}$$

show that
$$\left|a_{2n}-a_{n}\right|<\dfrac{10}{27}$$
and the constant  $\frac{10}{27}$ A smaller number instead

$$a_{n+1}+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}=2(1+\sqrt{17})\cdot\dfrac{a_{n}+\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}}{4(2a_{n}+1)}\tag{1}$$
$$a_{n+1}-\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{4}=-2(-1+\sqrt{17})\cdot\dfrac{a_{n}-\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{4}}{4(2a_{n}+1)}\tag{2}$$
$\dfrac{(1)}{(2)}$,that
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}}{a_{n+1}-\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{4}}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{1-\sqrt{17}}\cdot\left(\dfrac{a_{n}+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}}{a_{n}-\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{4}}\right)$$
so we I get ugly even more can't solve this problem.can you some recommended or solve this?

Comment: Prove by induction

Comment: can you post full solution,because I found it's nod easy,even more ugly

Comment: @Sigma,Assmue that $ |a_{2n}-a_{n}|<\dfrac{27}{10}$,then consider $|a_{2(n+1)}-a_{n+1}|?$ or other?

Comment: I think this problem exist without induction methods and simple,and we consider How to replace the smaller numbers? because this absult,use induction maybe can't works?

Comment: Aren't all the terms between 1 and 2/3?

Comment: @Sigma "Prove by induction" I do not understand this comment. Did you have a specific idea in mind when you posted this or is it a shot in the dark? (Apparently, 5 users not only know how to apply your hint (I don't) but think that it yields the best solution. Beats me.)

Comment: @Did a shot in the dark. After that I tried to do so but I failed which I thought is most likely because I'm lacking approximation skills..apparently 5 other people were agreeing, so I didn't delete the comment :-D

Comment: @Sigma Posting shots in the dark is allright *but only if you mention them as such*. You did quite the opposite here since your comment reads as "I did it by induction, I am absolutely sure this is the best way, just follow me". Indeed I would delete the comment if I were you (and please do not get me started on upvotes on mse... :-)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1/2}$ maps $[2/3,1]$ to $[2/3,6/7] \subset [2/3,1]$, since $1/3 < 10/27$ the result follows.

Comment: you mean $a_{n}\in [2/3,1]$ for all $n?$

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean

Comment: I think  this methods  is very nice +1

Comment: so $|a_{2n}-a_{n}|\le 1/3$  the $\dfrac{1}{3}$ is best constant for $n$,because $a_{2}-a_{1}=\dfrac{1}{3}$,

Comment: @functionsug Indeed, and, for each $N$, a constant such that $|a_{2n}-a_n|\leqslant c_N$ for every $n\geqslant N$ is $c_N=|a_{N+1}-a_N|$. Note that $(c_N)$ is decreasing and that $c_N\to0$ when $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did,Nice  ,and How to prove $c_{N}\to 0,N\to+\infty$?

Comment: @functionsug *Contraction property*... Let $\ell$ in $[\frac23,1]$ solve $f(\ell)=\ell$. Since $|f'(\ )|\leqslant r$ on $[\frac23,1]$, with $r=\frac67$, one knows that $|a_n-\ell|\leqslant r^{n-1}\cdot|a_1-\ell|$ for every $n$, qed.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let $p=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}$ and $q=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{4}$

Let $b_{n}=\frac{a_{n}+p}{a_{n}-q}$, then your last equation can be rewritten as follows:

$b_{n+1}=\frac{p}{q}b_{n}$

Since the above is a geometric sequence,  we have $b_{n}=b_{1}r^{n-1}$, where $r=\frac{p}{q}$.

Unsubstitting, we have $\frac{a_{n}+p}{a_{n}-q}=b_{1}r^{n-1}$.

So $a_{n}=\frac{qb_{1}r^{n-1}+p}{b_{1}r^{n-1}-1}$

I think you can derive your desired inequality using extra conditions such as $a_{1}=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I known this,But How to prove inequality?

Comment: I don't understand why this anwer has been downvoted (I upvote immediately). It is perfectly economical in its explanations : the auxiliary sequence $b_n$ being a geometric sequence is very easy to manipulate. see for example [this](http://homedir.jct.ac.il/~math/tutorials/infitut1/node27.html)

Comment: @JeanMarie Can you perform the missing step? If you answer "no", you have an idea about why people may downvote this and why you may want to revise your immediate-upvote procedure. (To prevent misunderstandings, I didn't vote yet, but only because I did not fully check this is a deadend although I suspect it is.)

Comment: @Did I just think that  Sah-moo Kim is fully in the spirit of this site by 1) taking into account where the OP has met a difficulty, 2) abstract it by using economical notations and giving the name "geometrical sequence" for the auxiliary sequence he uses. I agree on the fact that there is a missing step. I would fill it like this : as the terms of  $b_n$ can be confined in an arbitrarily small vicinity of $0$, this property is transferred by continuity of a certain $f(x)=(rx+t)/(ux+v)$ to the $a_n \rightarrow L$ which thus can be confined for ex. in $(L-5/27,L+5/27)$ for all $n > n_0.$

Comment: @JeanMarie The spirit of the site is to downvote posts that do not answer the questions. Re the "filling in" you suggest: indeed, various methods show that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges hence, for every $n$ large enough, yes, $|a_{2n}-a_n|\leqslant0.00001$. The question is quite different since it asks to show the upper bound $\frac{10}{27}$ for every $n$. So it seems we are back at my "deadend" conjecture (sorry).

Comment: Yes. But one must recognize that to such an artificial question (it could have been as well $|a_{3^n}-a_{23n}|$...), some answers concentrate only on the important fact, the convergence...

Comment: @JeanMarie Again: "the important fact" here is to answer the question as it is. If one does not like a question but one wants to post an answer, then one can write a post explaining why the question is bad **and** answering it, not only the former.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a proof**, only an indication that this issue is situated in $|a_2-a_1|$ only (because afterwards, it is a classical oscillatory convergence). 
When you look at the first values of the sequence :

$a_1=1, a_2=2/3=0.66667, a_3=6/7=0.85714, a_4=14/19=0.73684, a_5=38/47=0.80851, a_6=94/123=0.76423, a_7=246/311=0.79100, a_8=622/803=0.77460, 0.78456, 0.77847, 0.78218, 0.77992, 0.78130, 0.78046, 0.78097, 0.78066, 0.78085, 0.78073, 0.78080, 0.78076, ....$

you understand that the "hard core" of what has to be proved is essentially in the first cases and in $|a_2-a_1|$ mainly.

$|a_2-a_1| = \dfrac{1}{3} <  \dfrac{10}{27}=0.37037...$, rather tight, but

$|a_4-a_2| = \dfrac{4}{57}=0.07017$ is much smaller than $\dfrac{10}{27}$

$|a_8-a_4| = \dfrac{576}{15257}=0.0377... << 10/27$, and so on...

We are far from being with a tight bound... So, may I ask to the author of this question, what has motivated her/him (homework, or personal research) for being interested in $a_{2n}-a_n$ and not in $a_{3n}-a_{2n}$ or...

Comment: middle school exam problem